# How to make a catch block with more arguments that i catch it from objects from classes for exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have three exceptions classes in my code, so when i want to use more arguments (more different objects to catch i get an compile error) so how i can catch more exceptions?

i tried to do this

```
try{
        User * u = new FacebookUser(username,password,email,friends,likes,comments);
        network += u;
        }
        catch(InvalidPassword ip,InvalidEmail ie,MaximumSizeLimit ms){
            ip.message();
            ie.message();
            ms.message():
        }
```

First exception is for checking if password have at least 1 uppercase,lowercase and number.

Second exception is for checking if email have at least 1 `@` .

Third exception is for changing static variable, if the maximum is equal to `n` throw exception.

My throw exceptions for email and password are in my user constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple types of exceptions you want to catch, you need to catch them separately - otherwise, what would be in say `ip` if `InvalidEmail` was thrown?

Correct code will be like

```cpp
try {
    //...
} catch (const InvalidPassword& ip) {
    //...
} catch (const InvalidEmail& ie) {
    //...
} catch (const MaximumSizeLimit& ms) {
    //...
}
```

Othewrise, you can make all this exceptions inherited to the same base class and make `message` virtual function of this base class.

(as a separate note, it is sometimes considered bad style to use exceptions for such checks)